# How to replace list value with another value c#

Tags: c#, excel, csv

I write some data into `csv` file from List but some list indexes has empty string but another indexes has value
 in these cases the data compared with another list wrote in the same `csv` file 
this is my csv file opened using excel sheet
 
[image: T]

 
in the third column there exist ID for the the second column cell so in the coming rows i want to detect the name of the ID based on previous rows

like in row 3 it's ID is 19 and name is I/O so in the 7th row the ID is 19 and want to fill the second cell now
info : the IDs is already known above and any next ID will be exist before
by the follwing code.

```
bool isInList = ms.IndexOf(ShapeMaster) != -1; 
if (isInList) 
{ 
    savinglabelnamefortextbox = t.InnerText; 
     string replacement = 
     Regex.Replace(savinglabelnamefortextbox,  @"\t|\n|,|\r", ""); 
    xl.Add("");
    dl.Add(replacement); 
    ms.Add(ShapeMaster); 
}
```

and I use the following code to write to the csv file

```
using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(csvfilename))
{ 
    for (int i = 0; i < dl.Count; i++) 
    { 
        var line = String.Format("{0},{1},{2}", dl[i], xl[i],ms[i]); 
        sw.WriteLine(line);
    } 
}
```

Comment: What's the question? Are you just trying to put the value from row 3 column 2 (`I/O`) into every Column 2 where Column 3 is 19 AND Column 2 is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
            for (int x = 0; x < ms.Count; x++)
        {
            if (xl[x] != "")
            {
                continue;
            }
            else if (xl[x] == "")
            {
                for (int y = 0; y<xl.Count; y++)
                {
                    if (ms[y] == ms[x])
                    {
                        xl[x] = xl[y];
                        break;
                    }
                }
                continue;
            }
        }
```